# how can i achieve case when in python and aggregation between columns

Tags: python, pandas

I used SQL and SAS before and now I am turning to Python recently. And there are lots of problems I meet. I am still working on them and there is a new problem that drives me crazy:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
data = {'Period':['2016-02','2016-02','2016-02','2016-02','2016-03','2016-03','2016-04'],
'Name':['a','b','c','c','d','e','v'],
'amount':[2,3,41,1,8,43,20],
'Credit':[5,2,45,50,9,21,32]}
```

How can I get the same result like SQL does:

```
select *,case when Period = '2016-02' then (amount/Credit)*1.2
              when Period = '2016-03' then (amount/Credit)*1.1
         else (amount/Credit)*1.0 end as Rate from data
```

or like SAS does:

```
data data;
set data;
if Period = '2016-02' then rate=(amount/Credit)*1.2;
else if Period = '2016-03' then rate=(amount/Credit)*1.1;
else rate=(amount/Credit)*1.0;
run;
```

or even more:

```
select Period,min(amount,credit) from data group by Period;
```

Comment: What have you tried? If you know about lists, for loops and accessing dictionaries then this is a simple problem to work through.

Comment: Can you show the expected result for the example data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***option 1 `pandas`***
use `map`

```
m = lambda x: 1.2 if x == '2016-02' else 1.1 if x == '2016-03' else 1.
df.amount / df.Credit * df.Period.map(m)
```

***option 2 `numpy`***
`numpy.where`

```
p = df.Period.values
multiplier = np.where(p == '2016-02', 1.2, np.where(p == '2016-03', 1.1, 1.))
df.amount / df.Credit * multiplier
```

---

All yield

```
0    0.480000
1    1.800000
2    1.093333
3    0.024000
4    0.977778
5    2.252381
6    0.625000
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Sir i tried to answer the same question taking different approach, but i am getting some errors, can you help me in that please??  See my answer.

Comment: Awesome!That is exactly what i want! Thank you very much!

Comment: can i revise the script if i want to add another condition 'Name'. like :     select *,case when Period = '2016-02' and Name = 'c' then (amount/Credit)*1.2
              when Period = '2016-03' and and Name = 'e' then (amount/Credit)*1.1
         else (amount/Credit)*1.0 end as Rate from data

Answer (score 0):

```
a = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
def func(name):
c = a[a['Name'] == name]
if c['Period'] == '2016-02':
    c['rate'] = c['amount'] / c['Credit']*1.2
    return c
elif c['Period'] == '2016-03':
    c['rate'] = c['amount'] / c['Credit']*1.1
    return c 
else:
    c['rate'] = c['amount'] / c['Credit']*1.0
    return c

x = a['Name'].apply(func)
```

Comment: **1)** you pass `row` but are referencing `a`.  **2)** when you `apply` your are operating on a `pd.Series`, when you reference an index value of a `pd.Series` like `a['amount']` that is going to be a scalar.  It won't have a method named `div`.  **3)** you are testing for equality with an assignment operator `a['Period'] = '2016-02'`

Comment: @piRSquared Sir i changed my code as per your instructions , but i am getting value error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`  If you could maybe edit some parts of my code , thus it will help me in understanding and learning better

Answer (score 0):

The first way is probably the most straight forward in which you just iterate through and grab each value from the lists then adding it to a resulting list.

```
import pprint # used here to output results nicely

data = {
    'Period':['2016-02','2016-02','2016-02','2016-02','2016-03','2016-03','2016-04'],
    'Name':['a','b','c','c','d','e','v'],
    'amount':[2,3,41,1,8,43,20],
    'Credit':[5,2,45,50,9,21,32]
}

res = []
count = len(data['Period'])

for i in range(count):

    period = data['Period'][i]
    name = data['Name'][i]
    amount = data['amount'][i]
    credit = data['Credit'][i]

    if period == '2016-02':
        rate = amount / credit * 1.2
    elif period == '2016-03':
        rate = amount / credit * 1.1
    else:
        rate = amount / credit * 1.0

    res.append( ( period, name, amount, credit, rate ) )

pprint.pprint(res)
```

A more compact solution would be

```
res = [ [(p, n, a, c,
    a/c * 1.2 if p == '2016-02' else a/c * 1.1 if p == '2016-03' else a/c * 1.0)]
   for p, n, a, c in zip(data['Period'], data['Name'], data['amount'], data['Credit']) ]

pprint.pprint(res)

# Output
[[('2016-02', 'a', 2, 5, 0.48)],
 [('2016-02', 'b', 3, 2, 1.7999999999999998)],
 [('2016-02', 'c', 41, 45, 1.0933333333333333)],
 [('2016-02', 'c', 1, 50, 0.024)],
 [('2016-03', 'd', 8, 9, 0.9777777777777779)],
 [('2016-03', 'e', 43, 21, 2.2523809523809524)],
 [('2016-04', 'v', 20, 32, 0.625)]]
```

Note that if you want a `numpy` solution look at piRSquared's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41800307/4831822) or a `pandas` solution look at S Ringne's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41800385/4831822).